# Is it possible (or even desirable) for a developer to publish multiple apps under different names?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am currently evaluating a mobile developer that I met online. He sent me a list of his published apps and there are a total of 33 apps in the list, mostly Native with a few in React Native.

The weird part is that every app I’ve checked so far has a different developer name and none of them match the personal name of the developer. (Yes, he could publish under a business name but one of the apps is (C) Aston Martin.)

Am I reading too much into this or is it actually as fishy as it smells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your title :
**Yes, it is possible provided the publisher have enough resources.**

There might be a few reason for a developer to publish the apps under different names/developer/publisher.

- The apps are developed for different clients, thus they would want to separate out the publishing to store (PlayStore or AppStore) part, so that when the clients decide they want to use the services of other publisher etc, the current publisher could just hand over the accounts related to that client. Such as emails, store accounts, hosting accounts, and possibly even bank and credit card account which could have been made under the client's company name to begin with. And it also allows the clients to handle the informations of the Apps at the store themselves easier.
- The company, for one reason or another does not want the published apps to be easily traced back to the same company. Maybe because of tax-evasion, privacy issues, or simply because the content of the apps is not totally legal to be distributed in the country where the developer is operating from.

But considering your description of "evaluating a mobile developer that I met online." There are a few possibilities that the apps are published under different names

- The apps are build while he is working under different companies.
- The apps he listed are apps that uses one/few libraries that he made.
- He was working under freelance jobs for company(ies) that in the end developed the apps for those companies published separately.
- He was simply lying that those are his apps to get your approval, since you can't really trace back so many step without a legal court request to the store (PlayStore and AppStore) to know that he is really the one developing it.

One easy way to validate for PlayStore is to have them send you an email (or a few) using the registered email address at the bottom of the PlayStore listing page of the apps for one or few of the apps.

For example [Facebook Lite's](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.litelite-android-support@fb.com) would be lite-android-support@fb.com.

But if they are working under another company, or such, they would not have access to the said email address, and you would have to ask them to provide other ways to validate their relations to the projects listed.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think that gave me enough to look for a different developer.